# Need to change or Stop Android 8 Recent App Thumbnail Shortcut Or Activity

Tags: user-interface, android-8.1-oreo, android-recents

In recent apps... if I touch the thumbnail on top left corner of app Title Bar for any app, it goes to an i icon for information.  Then, it goes to entire App Information.

I need to know HOW I can stop that Activity from taking place.

This may seem very miniscule. However; in my current setting, this is a huge security threat**.
**

Any help, advice, and/or suggestions would be tremendously appreciated!

Thank you Android Community ! ! !

I have already tried using a System UI Tuner to no avail.

Maybe ApkTool is a solution?